# How can I pass a JS object literal name value pair to another function

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Given a JS literal object like:

```
var foo = {
    _stuff : {
        a:10,
        b:20,
        c:30,
        state
    }
}
```

and literal functions

```
addAB: function() {
    add(foo._stuff[a], foo._stuff[b]);
}

addAC: function() {
    add(foo._stuff[a], foo._stuff[c]);
}

add: function(bar, baz) {
    foo._stuff[bar] += foo._stuff[baz];
    state(foo._stuff[bar]);
}

state: function(value) {
   foo.state[value] = .... something complex ....
}
```

How can I get the following in one pass ?

```
add(AB); foo._stuff[a] should be 30, foo.state[foo._stuff[a]] is something new
add(AC); foo._stuff[a] should be 40, foo.state[foo._stuff[a]] is something new
```

As is add() will try to lookup foo._stuff[10] which clearly wont do what I want.

Yes I know there is redundancy with addAB() and addAC() but that is out of my control.

Comment: "Given a JS literal object like:" --- it's syntactically incorrect

Comment: For what you're talking about, the `addAB` and `addAC` functions should be calling `add` with `'a', 'b'` and `'a', 'c'`, respectivly, not `foo._stuff['a']`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the index instead of the value, like this:

```
addAB: function() {
    add('a', 'b');
}

addAC: function() {
    add('a', 'c');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add: function(bar, baz) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        this['add' + arguments[0]];
    } else {
      foo._stuff[bar] += foo._stuff[baz];
      state(foo._stuff[bar]);
    }
}

// assuming you are calling
var AB = 'AB', AC = 'AC';
add(AB); 
add(AC);
```

Otherwise, I have not a clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally follow what you want to accomplish, but your object literal is not valid syntax. I don't see why you want the `_stuff` property. And, you need to initialize the `state` property to some value, even if it's undefined. But, since you want to store values in the `state` property based on some property name, you should initialize `state` to be an object.

```
var foo = {
    a:10,
    b:20,
    c:30,
    state: {}
}
```

Your javascript:

```
addAB: function() {
    add('a', 'b');
}

addAC: function() {
    add('a', 'c');
}

add: function(propName0, propName1) {
    foo[propName0] += foo[propName1];
    state(propName0);
}

state: function(propName) {
    // state is initialized to an object, so can store properties in there now
   foo.state[propName] = .... something complex ....
}
```